# how to get rotations with the date of the previous day?

Tags: linux, logs, logrotate

Every day at midnight, the achievement processes with logrotate begin, which I have set up.

But I'm faced with the problem that once the rotation is finished, it has the name of the current day and I'm interested in the name being the previous day.

My version of logrotate is: 
3.8.6

My configuration file logrotate.conf contains:

```
/mylogs/thelogs {
    missingok
    daily
    copytruncate
    create 0644 root utmp
    rotate 6
    dateyesterday
}
```

I've tried changing 'dataext' to 'dateyesterday' but it's still doing exactly the same thing.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looking at `man logrotate`, I think you need to give both `dateext` _and_ `dateyesterday`, otherwise you probably get .1, .2 etc. again.

Comment: then if I understand correctly, the configuration should be: `/mylogs/thelogs {
    missingok
    daily
    copytruncate
    create 0644 root utmp
    rotate 6
    dateext
    dateyesterday
}`

I'll try it... thank you.

Comment: I have tried using only dateyesterday, but also leaving dateext and dateyesterday together. But it does not change the name of the log, the date of the current day applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By having the rotate configuration both within two files:

etc/logrotate.conf 
etc/logrotate.d/syslog

The changes I made were not working properly.

After leaving the configuration only in logrotate.conf; the answer of Ulrich Schwarz in the comments has worked correctly.

Greetings

Answer (score 3):

I add my experience

I need both `dateext` and `dateyesterday` options.

If I omit `dateext`, I obtain numbered files (.1, .2, .3, etc...)